# Inheritance and Lock in EJB

Tags: java, ejb

Does a method defined in a subclass EJB bean inherit the @Lock annotation,either from the superclass(if @Lock is used at class level in superclass ) or from a method it has overriden(if @Lock is used at method level in superclass) in EJB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the definition of Lock

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Lock.html

It has no metaannotation `@Inherited` so i guess the lock is not propagated to subclasses and overriden methods.